# Short if-statement "inside" short if-statement

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, operators, short

This is my task, and I'm trying to do that with the short if-statements only, the only error I get is that with the syntax where there's   "***(0.5<=ratio<2)***", other than that, Is the construction right?
[image]

```
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int years,kg,cm,MenuA,MenuB,MenuC,A,B,C;
    String not;
    double ratio = cm/kg;
    System.out.println("Please enter your age (years), weight(kg) and height(cm) in that order with spaces");
    years = scn.nextInt();
    kg = scn.nextInt();
    cm = scn.nextInt();

    MenuA = (20<years<<11||40<<years<21)&&(0.5<=ratio<2)?A:MenuB;
    MenuB = (20<years<<11)&&(2<=ratio<<3.5)?B:MenuC;
    MenuC = (40<<years<21)&&(2<=ratio<<3.5)?C:not;

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you bitshifting? You've done "20 < years << 11" which reads as "20 smaller than years left-shift 11 times"

Comment: You also can't write `0.5<=ratio<2`. It's just not a syntax supported by Java.

Comment: I think you are under a misconception that you can have an expression similar to `5 < x < 7` to express "x is between 5 and 7". This doesn't exist in Java. And `<<` is indeed a shift operation, not a comparison operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
20 < years < 11
```

That's not valid Java code. No matter which of the operands you evaluate first, the result will be of type `boolean` which does not compare to `int`.

You'll need to do it the long way:

```
20 < years && years < 11
```

Or create a method for this:

```
betweenExclude(20, years, 11);
```

with

```
boolean betweenExclude(int a, int b, int c) {
   return a < b && b < c;
}
```

and maybe also

```
boolean betweenIncludeLeft(double left, double number, double right) {
  return left <= number && number < right;
}
```

In terms of readability / maintainability you should also consider writing this in a way, that is easily translated into your table:

```
enum Age {
  ELEVEN_TO_TWENTY,
  TWENTYONE_TO_FORTY
};

Age age; 
if(between(11, years, 20)) {
   age = Age.ELEVEN_TO_TWENTY;
}
if(between(21, years, 40)) {
   age = Age.TWENTYONE_TO_FORTY;
}
```

Similar for the weight to height ratio

And later

```
if(age.euqals(Age.TWENTYONE_TO_FORTY) && weightratio.equals(WeightRatio.LOW)) {
   //A 
}
```

**Comment**

Your age-check should *include* both your boundaries. 11 and 20 have to be *in*, otherwise people of age 10 and 11 will drop out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, that did the trick:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class elevator {
    public static void main(String[] args){

```
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int years;
    double kg,cm;
    System.out.println("Please enter your age (years), weight(kg) and height(cm) in that order with spaces");
    years = scn.nextInt();
    kg = scn.nextDouble();
    cm = scn.nextDouble();
    double ratio = cm/kg;
    int MenuA,MenuB,MenuC;
    int A,B,C;

    MenuC = (21<=years&&years<=40)&&(2<=ratio&&ratio<3.5)?'C':'N';
    MenuB = (11<=years&&years<=20)&&(2<=ratio&&ratio<3.5)?'B':MenuC;
    MenuA = ((11<=years&&years<=20||21<=years&&years<=40)&&(0.5<=ratio&&ratio<2))?'A':MenuB;

    System.out.println("Your menu is: " + (char)MenuA);

}
```

}